# Complex grouping case - using "delimiting tinyint flag" between groups

Tags: sql, postgresql

Below is the an example of the page-views dataset in question.

Presented records are sorted in ASC order by a timestamp.

[image]

I need to calculate some per-session measures from the dataset.

The problem is that there is no clear identifier for a session. The only thing that is available is `is_a_new_session` flag - which serves as a kind of a delimiter between sessions. So, in the given example there are 5 separate sessions.

How could I generate some sort of a session identifier and add it to the dataset, so that I can later use it for grouping per session?

The desired new column would like similar to this:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a cumulative sum to define the groups and then aggregate:

```
select min(timestamp), max(timestamp), . . .   -- whatever columns you want
from (select t.*,
             sum(is_a_new_session) over (order by timestamp) as grp
      from t
     ) t
group by grp;
```

Comment: That was so easy.. Embarrassed about not seeing it myself. Thank you Gordon!